# unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

When I start my server I get thes error, but the server is still working fine !

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to
>   create new native thread  at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:658)  at
>   Gateway.main(Server.java:21)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    try {  
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));; 
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients");
      while (true) {         

          Child cServer = new Child(serverSocket);  
        cServer.start();  
      }  
    } catch (IOException ex) {  
      System.out.println(ex);  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Child class

```
public Child(DatagramSocket ssocket) {  
         this.socket = ssocket;  

       }  


       public void run() {  
           while(true)
            {
               byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
```

EDIT:
I tried to make like in this example, it work fine here

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        server = new MyServer();
        server.runServer();
    }

    private void runServer() {        
        int serverPort = 8071;
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting Server");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort); 

            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for request");
                try {
                    Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("Processing request");
                    executorService.submit(new ServiceRequest(s));
                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Error accepting connection");
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException e)
```

Comment: Just how many of those threads do you intend to start?!

Comment: Wow, you don't just start a server, you start *many* servers. How many? It's hard to tell, but you do it till you run out of threads.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new Child objects in an infinite while loop until all available memory is consumed.

Comment: How many servers to you need to have listening? I would guess only one. Just start up one thread at a time until your byte[] is filled and then process it and end the thread, then set another to listen. Maybe your child should implement Runnable and then you could use a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor. Why don't you look for a solution to the real problem you need to solve and copy it. There is a lot to be learned by that methodology.

Answer (score 1):

Does `new Child()` or `cServer.start()` block?  I'm suspicious that your `while (true)` is a rapid infinite loop that chews up your heap space.  Once the OutofMemoryError is thrown (milliseconds at most), the app finishes and the server reclaims all that memory, so it looks like your server is still working.

Comment: In your example code, `Socket s = serverSocket.accept();` blocks, waiting for a connection.  So it won't loop fast like your posted code will.  You need to call `accept()` or something similar.